# HTTPS request, specifying hostname and specific IP address

Tags: node.js, https

I have a Node.js-based deployment script for my application servers.  One step in the deployment process is to validate that these application servers are listening on HTTPS correctly before registering them with DNS.  To do that, I simply need to make an HTTPS request to that server's IP address.

If this were HTTP, it's a non-issue.  I can make a HTTP `GET` request for `http://[2001:0db8::0370:7334]/`, and this will work.  However, if I make an HTTPS GET request for `https://[2001:0db8::0370:7334]/`, this will fail since the certificate is for a specific hostname like `api.example.com`.

If I were testing manually, I would temporarily put the IP address in the `hosts` file and cURL `https://api.example.com`.  However, in this automated process, I may be deploying several hosts at once so this isn't a solution for my deployment script.

How can I make an HTTPS request where I specify the hostname and IP address?

Perhaps there's some way to do this with a custom Agent?

I'm currently using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), but I'm happy to use whatever API is needed to make this work.

Comment: It seems like you're asking to circumvent validating certs to validate https (which requires certs) ... why not just use the hostname if you've got it?

Comment: @CodyG. No, I'm trying to do the opposite.  I want to validate the cert.

Comment: welp, probably the only way is to modify the dns lookup function, as the module suggested in this package does. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026131/node-override-request-ip-resolution but it might not work in newer version of node...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `host` header for the request:

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://AA.BB.CC.DD', {
  headers : { host : 'api.example.com' }
}, res => {
  console.log('okay');
}).on('error', e => {
  console.log('E', e.message);
});
```

**EDIT**: I dug around a bit to see how this works exactly. To allow HTTPS-based virtual hosting, there's a TLS extension called [SNI (Server Name Indication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). This extension is used by a client to indicate the hostname to which it is trying to connect, so the server can pick the appropriate certificate that belongs to that hostname.

Node's `tls` module, which is used by `https`, has an option [`servername`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback) to set this hostname:

```
https.get('https://AA.BB.CC.DD', {
  servername : api.example.com'
}, ...)
```

However, you still need to pass a `Host` header too (that's part of the regular HTTP protocol):

```
https.get('https://AA.BB.CC.DD', {
  headers : { host : 'api.example.com' },
  servername : 'api.example.com'
}, ...)
```

To keep things DRY, Node.js will set `servername` to the `Host` header, unless it's already set to something else ([here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/175164e5d12829b46f91137a01dac72f236a37be/lib/_http_agent.js#L232)).

Comment: Cool, it works!  Any chance you can explain why it works?  Seems that the HTTP headers shouldn't have anything to do with the TLS layer of things.  Is there something internal to Node.js modules that is re-using this header value?

Comment: @Brad see edit. You're correct, Node.js _is_ re-using the header value.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the additional research and explanation!  I'll award the bounty once Stack Overflow lets me.