# One signal create notification REST API fails sometimes

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, onesignal

I am using `oneSignal` for push notifications `node.js`. I am using the create notification api to send notification to the users, but i dont know why it works some times and sometimes gives timeout error

```
sendNotificationToUser(data) {
    try {
        var notificationData = {}
        notificationData.app_id = oneSignalAppId
        notificationData.headings = {
            en: "Heading"
        }
        notificationData.contents = {
            en: data.message
        }
        notificationData.include_player_ids = [data.deviceId]

        var headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }
        var options = {
            host: "onesignal.com",
            port: 443,
            path: "/api/v1/notifications",
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers
        }

        var https = require("https")
        var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
            res.on("data", function (data1) {
                console.log("Response:")
                console.log(JSON.parse(data1))
            })
        })

        req.on("error", function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR:")
            console.log(e)
        })

        req.write(JSON.stringify(notificationData))
        req.end()
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("err in notification", err)
    }
}
```

this api works 50% of times and 50% of times it responds with time out error, even all the inputs are correct

```
ERROR:
 { 
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.18.225.52:443
          at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
          errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
          syscall: 'connect',
          address: '104.18.225.52',
          port: 443
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason for encapsulating the whole functionality in one function as well as including require `https` in function scope rather than file scope?

Comment: Before this function i was using async-await with request-promise(rp) for calling oneSignals create notification api but it was also giving the same time out error so i thought maybe somehow rp or async-await might be causing these problems so i just copied the function from their official website you can find it here https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification (just scroll to bottom for Example Code - Create notification-nodejs) and boom it still gives the same error.

Comment: Its an open issue from oneSignal .. please follow-up the discussion at https://github.com/zeyneloz/onesignal-node/issues/52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one simple solution is to directly hit the working ip, you can do this by including
host: 'onesignal.con' in headers and
host: '104.18.226.52' in options

this resolved my issue

to know more about how you can specify ip with host in https request
go here [HTTPS request, specifying hostname and specific IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522723/https-request-specifying-hostname-and-specific-ip-address)